# Dnsmasq cannot create listening socket for port 53

Tags: dnsmasq, raspbian

I am trying to set up a DNS server on a Raspberry pi running Raspbian. I have been following tutorials online on how to setup a DNS server, and I found this one that was very easy to follow.

http://www.heystephenwood.com/2013/06/use-your-raspberry-pi-as-dns-cache-to.html

I followed the directions and installed dnsmasq via the link listed on this site

`curl "https://raw.github.com/stephendotexe/raspberrypi/master/roles/dnsmasq_server" | sudo sh`,

but when it attempted to start dnsmasq, it gave me the error;

```
dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use failed!
```

I did some research and I came across this post on the Askubuntu site.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/191226/dnsmasq-failed-to-create-listening-socket-for-port-53-address-already-in-use

Again, I followed the directions and it appeared that dnsmasq interferes with Network Manager, so I ran the following commands, as directed by the post.

```
sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq-base
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

Again, this didn't solve my problem. I tried to use `lsof` to figure out what is using port 53, so I installed it with `sudo apt-get install lsof` and ran the command;

`sudo lsof -Pn +M | grep ':53 (LISTEN)`

I got this output

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
named   1955 bind   20u  IPv4   2467      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:53 (LISTEN)
named   1955 bind   21u  IPv4   2469      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.102:53 (LISTEN)
named   1955 bind  512u  IPv4   2466      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:53 
named   1955 bind  513u  IPv4   2468      0t0  UDP 192.168.0.102:53
```

I assume this means I need to uninstall BIND or at least make it not execute on startup.

Comment: You need to run `lsof` as root: `sudo lsof +M -nPi :53`

Comment: Ok. I think that BIND is taking up port 53, but I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the readout correctly. There are 5 processes running and under the USER column they all say `bind`. Does this mean that BIND is running and I need to uninstall it?

`COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME`

`named   1955 bind   20u  IPv4   2467      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:53 (LISTEN)`

`named   1955 bind   21u  IPv4   2469      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.102:53 (LISTEN)`

`named   1955 bind  512u  IPv4   2466      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:53 `

`named   1955 bind  513u  IPv4   2468      0t0  UDP 192.168.0.102:53`

Comment: Also BIND is a DNS server, correct?

Comment: Yes, `bind`/`named` is a DNS server. You could edit your question and include the output of that `lsof` command.

Comment: I fixed it. I cannot answer my question for another 7 hours, however.

Answer (score 1):

in your DNSMASQ.conf, be sure TFTP is disabled for the concerned interface (eth8 in my case, replace by yours)

```
# = dont provide DHCP or TFTP on this interface : (BUT provide DNS service)
no-dhcp-interface=eth8
```

Comment: What DNSMASQ.conf?